# Are large spikes/fluctuations in validation loss an issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

When I apply Batch Normalisation to my CNN, it massively improves the training loss but the **validation keeps fluctuating significantly** (even though still better than it was before BN was applied). And the training loss seems to be overfitting (or so I think).

I have read a lot about optimum location of BN layer and even been told that Pooling is no longer used in most state of the art NN so I should probably get rid of it.

**So my question is:**

Is it an issue to have these fluctuations during training, even though both validation and training seem to converge close to each other?

(Learning Curve and CNN architecture attached) All layers use Relu.

```
Conv-1D
BN
Conv-1D
BN
APool

Conv-1D
BN
Conv-1D
MPool

Flatten
Dense
BN
Dense
Output
```

[Learning Curve Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkUsh.png)

Comment: You could try changing `momentum` in `BatchNormalization` to `0.9` as the default value is `0.99`.

Comment: Is it worth optimising the momentum term (using keras-tuner), or is 0.9 a commonly used good value?

Comment: Yup you should see less fluctuation in the loss.

Comment: Your layer looks fine, for fluctuations try shuffling the data and train model. If the fluctuation is more try tuning the hyper-parameters like learning rate, momentum,batch size(start with smaller scale).  If the fluctuation is normal then it's fine.